# Change in Facebook API policy

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am reading a blog which has mentioned "April 2015, apps will no longer be able to access friends on Facebook"

http://www.beehiveid.com/blog/dramatic-change-to-facebook-api-policy-enhances-privacy

Is it true??

Answer (score 1):

You could start reading the Facebook docs which have been around since exactly one year at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app.

Comment: "reading the docs" is as out as "using google"

Comment: Yes, I wonder why I'm not tired of explaining this over and over, yet...

Comment: well....easy points, you know :) - but it´s still sad.